# I cant get the inferno fork!

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have pretty much every single hard mode weapon, but I have killed a bunch of diabolists, and haven't got one! Is there a way to increase the drop chance?

Answer (score 1):

The [Inferno Fork](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Inferno_Fork) drops from [Diabolists](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Diabolist) post-Plantera.

While the official wiki rates the drop rate as [5%, or 7.5%](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Diabolist) on [Expert Mode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Expert_Mode), a [different wiki](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Inferno_Fork) rates the drop rate as 2.5%.

This means that, on average, you should have to kill anywhere from 20-40 Diabolists, although you could get unlucky and have to kill more.

While enemies are tougher in Expert Mode, drop rates increase, so that may be a suitable option to increase drop chance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem with the game, but it's a problem with luck. I haven't gotten an Inferno Fork yet, and I killed like what, 80 something Diablos? Anyway, the best way to get them is find somewhere they spawn and put a Water Candle down and drink Battle Potions consecutively. Using a minion or two might help you battle faster. Another trick is to pinch your screen so your avatar is close up if you're a Melee player. It somehow increases the spawn radius for monsters and gives a better chance for more Diablos. That's what me and my friend did to get one. He took it before I did though.

Answer (score -1):

It can take anywhere from 2-30+ kills of diabolists to get the drop. It is very rare, so they don't just drop them every time! On Mobile, I don't think there's a way to increase the chances. I would keep trying at it and keep killing the diabolists!

If you have already killed or you end up killing around 50 and still nothing, you might want to see if there is maybe a problem, but from what I can see, it's natural to have bad luck with drops!